# Line integral bounded by vertices of a square

Tags: integration, line-integrals, greens-theorem

Let C be the square with four corners $$(1,1), (-1,1), (-1,-1), (1,-1)$$ oriented counter clockwise.How would I calculate $$\int_{C}x^3\vec{i}+(x^2y)\vec{j}ds$$

I have attached an image of my steps if anyone is interested. I'm not sure if they are correct.[mysolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pSLIW.png)

Comment: Looks correct to me :)

Comment: Yes it's correct. No problem at all.